# Webview missing from Chrome

Tags: wpf, google-chrome, webview, microsoft-edge, webview2

We have an embedded microApp that is setup on a thirdparty website (Saba) that is designed to pass a session token to our Application. We are initiating a User login by presenting them an embedded browser session using WebView2 in our wpf application. Then after a successful login the microApp on the Saba homepage passes back a session token. This appears to be where the application is hanging, waiting for the valid session token to be returned.

This had been working great up until the last 24 hrs, when we are experience hangs on logging in. It appears that trying to access webview via the console/inspector from Edge doesn't work either. "window.chrome.webview" shows undefined.

We are actively scouring any reference we can find to see if there is information about webview support being deprecated or moved but we haven't yet. If anyone has any ideas or resources of where we may be able to find some answer that would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is not deprecated and not moved. chrome.webview should still exist in WebView2. It doesn't exist in the Edge browser. You can try using DevTools in the WebView2 itself (via the CoreWebView2.OpenDevToolsWindow() method or the Inspect context menu item) to see if chrome.webview exists or whatever else might be going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the response @DavidRisney!

It appears that the old code that we had been using in the microApp was failing when calling "window.chrome.webview", however it is working now as, "window.parent.chrome.webview". I am not an expert with web implementations but it appears to me that this must have been caused by the host (Saba) changing something on their side.

They say they didn't change anything. however, I tried to test on an unpatched Windows machine and saw the same issue. Are there any recent changes that could've changed the window relationship? Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: I did a [simple test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2McR.png) in WinodwsForm and found that `window.chrome.webview` works normally, so I am not sure what might be wrong with the code. If possible, can you provide relevant code examples?